# Browsermob selenium python - JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob-proxy, browsermob

Trying to get HAR files for a bunch of urls using browsermob-proxy with selenium in Python.
For the basic implementation, I'm using the sample code from [Browsermob documentation](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). My code below

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
import psutil
import time

server = Server(“/path/to/bin/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

from selenium import webdriver
profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

proxy.new_har(“google”) 
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print(proxy.har) #ISSUE IN THIS LINE

server.stop()
driver.quit()
```

I'm able to initialize browsermob-proxy, and get selenium to open the page on firefox (and chrome).
When it gets to the 'proxy.har' line, it throws a  JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Error trace below

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f690bb4c2c08> in <module>()
----> 1 proxy.har

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/browsermobproxy/client.py in har(self)
    102         r = requests.get('%s/proxy/%s/har' % (self.host, self.port))
    103 
--> 104         return r.json()
    105 
    106     def new_har(self, ref=None, options=None, title=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    890                     # used.
    891                     pass
--> 892         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    893 
    894     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've tried a bunch of things to resolve this, but can't get it to work

- The GET request returns 200
- Tried some json functions to load or parse to utf-8 or strip invalid characters
- Tried simplejson
- Tried changing browsermob port
- Tried on different networks in case the block was being caused by proxy settings

I get the same error no matter what I try. 
I initially thought the issue was with my installation. This is how I did it:

1. Installed selenium using pip3 (using python 3.6 with Jupyter/iPython)
2. Downloaded browsermob binary from https://bmp.lightbody.net/
3. Downloaded geckodriver
4. Started the proxy using ./browsermob-proxy within /bin, and also tried selecting the port using -port

Anyone had similar issues, which they resolved using anything other than the ones described above?

Comment: same question, upgrade to py3.7 also can not resolve

Comment: [jojoman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14674893/jojoman) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927904/12695027) saying "..I run the .bat file. WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred..", so "Use java jdk under version 9!". Not sure of the relevance, but Selenium may be running Java.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "browsermob-proxy" package is not compatible with your Python version.  The package is written for Python 2.x, while you are using Python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, but get the same error in python2 as well. I had someone else try the same code in their machine, and it works for them in python3.6 (same as mine), so I'm guessing there is something wrong with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue when running Python 3.6 on OSX 10.14.

Solved by switching to Python 3.7 - works on both Linux and Mac.